# php send one mail with attachment and copy with out

Tags: php, attachment, mailer

I did my first application of mailer php today, very nice, sending 2 pdf attachments,

but for record keeping, I need a copy of the mail to go to another mail, but with out the attachments,

how to accomplish this please??

here the code (edit, sorry, )

form html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Alleycode HTML Editor">
<meta name="Description" content="Your description here...">
<meta name="Keywords" content="Your keywords here...">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="sendmail2.php">
<p>
<label>Name:</label> <br/> <input type="text" name="name" size="48" height="40"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Email:</label> <br/> <input type="text" name="email" size="48" height="40"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Child's Name:</label> <br/> <input type="text" name="childname" size="48"    height="40"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Site:</label>
<br/>
<textarea name="site" rows="2" cols="45" overflow:hidden>xx.com.au</textarea>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<label>Days:</label>
<br/>
<textarea name="days" rows="2" cols="45" overflow:hidden>Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,  Thursday, Friday</textarea>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
 <a href="xx/form.html">clear</a></p>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

sendmail2.php:

```
<?php
require("../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
include("email.php");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$childname = $_POST['childname'];
$site = $_POST['site'];
$days = $_POST['days'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "xxx.com"; // SMTP servers
$mail->Username = "xxx";   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxx"; // SMTP password
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);
$mail->From     = "xxx@ax.com.au";
$mail->FromName = "xxx_online";
$mail->Subject = "Message from Alouette";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAttachment("../attachs/x.pdf");
$mail->AddAttachment("../attachs/xd.pdf");
if($mail->Send()) {
echo "Message sent! Thanks !          ";
print('<a href="xu/mail/form.html">Reset and Back</a>');
} 
?>
```

email.php

```
<?php
$message = '
Hello  '.$name.', <br/>
we have received your interest in child care services for  '.$childname.' from the    '.$site.' website. <br/>
<br/>
 '.$days.' 
<br/> <br/>
Should you have any questions regarding the information on our enrolment form or  services please do not hesitate to contactkkk
<br/> <br/> <br/>

Regards, <br/>


<a href="mailto:x@x.com.au">x@nx.com.au</a>   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <a   href="http://www.nx.com.au" target="_new">www.neo-it.com.au</a> 
<br/> 
<strong>Childcare Management Services</strong>
<br/> <br/>


    '
    ?>
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show the code you are using right now.

Comment: just create the same mail without the attachments and send it?

Comment: maybe create the object and set up the message and what not then clone it before setting the recipients and adding the attachments...then send each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way with the help 
of [phpFreaks](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/php-coding-help/php-send-one-mail-with-attachment-and-copy-with-out/msg1516229/#msg1516229)

very simple!
thanks freaks!

Answer (score 0):

For sending a simple mail in PHP, you require:

- Receiver email ID
- Subject
- Message
- Headers

For attaching files, you've to use `multipart` Content-Type

So, you could write a custom function which accepts the variables required, and sends two mails - One where you want to send the mail with files attached, and the other to another email ID without attachments for Record Keeping.

Comment: hello, I just included the code, I didn't understand your answer yet, tnx